# Jitsi Iframe API. WebSocket connection failed: Data frame received after close

Tags: jitsi, jitsi-meet

We are using Jitsi Iframe API in a mobile app developed with Ionic 1 Cordova.

Once the meet starts, if we try to add more people by sending the email we get the following error in the browser console (using ‘Invite more people’):

**WebSocket connection to ‘wss://meet.jit.si/xmpp-websocket?room=0.mn13p1pq94o’ failed: Data frame received after close (strophe.umd.js:5463)**

Any suggestions?